# How do I create a custom event and fire it using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My Code :.....

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function demo()
{
    var win=window.open("demo.html",'_blank');
    alert('Requested Page Loaded...');
    win.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="demo" onClick="demo()"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to close the alert event dynamically using JavaScript event.
When alert is come in seen and it will close automatically using JavaScript event fire and close it..

Comment: You cannot close an alert dialog programmatically.

Comment: Its depend if cannot close then it will fire event like ok button press automatically.

Comment: `alert` dialogs are blocking. Even if it was possible to create such an event, you could not trigger it because no code can be executed while the dialog is shown.

Comment: Write @FelixKling it is not possible to fire any event when dialog is appear. But Can we Fire Bubble Event or Combine Event in Javascript like `KeyboardEvent + MouseEvent` both at the same time?

Or

Another Option is we can Loose Focus of Opening in New Tab and Set Focus of Current Tab. e.g. `window.focus();` and `window.blur();`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a pseudo-alert.
You can make it a modal if it is closed by a programmed event (instead of screen-triggered).

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/S64aw/) is a fiddle. (click on two colors to open and close alert.

HTML

```
<div class='testdiv'></div>
<div class='testdiv3'></div>
<div id='dialogtest' class='testdiv2'>Alert!</div>
```

CSS

```
.testdiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.testdiv3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: green;
}

.testdiv2 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$( ".testdiv2" ).dialog({
                       autoOpen: false,
                          modal: false,
                         height: 50,
                          width: 'auto',
                       position: { my: "right middle",
                                   at: "left middle",
                                  of : ".testdiv" } 
                           });

$('.testdiv').click(function(){
  $('.testdiv2').dialog('open');
});
$('.testdiv3').click(function(){
  $('.testdiv2').dialog('close');
});
```